# CKEditor cursor doesn't blink on focus in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ckeditor

When I click on a CKEditor instance in Chrome it sometimes fails to show a blinking cursor. Typing text after click works as expected, and cursor becomes visible and blinking after the first character.

Is there a workaround?

I observe this strange bug only in Chrome (30.0.1599.101 + Windows7), Firefox and IE work as expected.

[Here's a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paulftw/H2szq/)

- click on the editor in the bottom right part of it and observe lack of cursor.
- Start typing and cursor will appear.

My code to create an editor instance:

```
$('#modal').html("<textarea id=foo></textarea>");

$('textarea#foo').ckeditor({
  height: "300px",
  toolbarStartupExpanded: true,
  width: "100%"
});
```

Comment: Confirmed. Have you reported this in the CKEditor trac dev.ckeditor.com? Because it looks like a bug (it could be a chrome bug rather than a CKE bug though).

Comment: This is indeed a Chrome bug and it was fixed in CKEditor 4.2.2 (http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10945).

Comment: Thanks Reinmar, you guys are awesome! Reported 2 bugs, each got investigated within 12 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has already been fixed in 4.2.2
http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10945